# How to combine strings and handles in liquid

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

I am struggling with the combination of a string and a handle using data files in Jekyll.

I generate the menu for my Jekyll-site using a `nav.yml`-data file where `nav.title` is the title of menu entries. My aim is to translate that title depending on the active language. For that purpose, I have a `il8n.yml`-file with the respective translation and – using the polyglot-plugin -- I can access these translation strings by `{{site.data.il8n.term[site.active_lang]}}` where `term` is the phrase I want to translate.

This is straightforward, but I am running into problems when I try to combine the `nav.title`-string from my menu data file with the translation from the il8n-data file.

Is there a way to look up the entry for `nav.title` in the il8n-file? As an example, I have an entry for the menu item "Publications" in my `nav.yml`-data file:

```
- title: "publications"
  href: "/publications/"
```

and an entry for the translation of "publications" in my `il8n.yml`-data file:

```
- title: "publications"
  de: Publikationen
  en: Publications
```

Is there some way to combine these two handles? My current workaround is a `menu: true` entry in the il8n-file and a respective loop looking for that condition, but I would like to keep the translations separate from the menu items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your setup for il8n-data file, you can do :

```
<ul>
{% for item in site.data.nav %}
  <li>
  {% assign itemTranslation = site.data.il8n | where: 'title', item.title %}
  {{ itemTranslation[0][site.active_lang] }}
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

With a il8n.yml ordered like this :

```
publications:
  de: Publikationen
  en: Publications
toto is great:
  de: toto is great in german
  en: toto is great
```

You can do :

```
<ul>
{% for item in site.data.nav %}
    <li>{{ site.data.il8n2[item.title][site.active_lang] }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```